# Cypress: Getting The task 'gmail:get-messages' returned undefined. in Cypress 10 but its working on older version of cypress

Tags: plugins, cypress

I am using cypress `gmail-tester`. I have updated cypress to `10` or above version and `gmail-tester` return the below error.

```
cy.task('gmail:get-messages') failed with the following error:

The task 'gmail:get-messages' returned undefined. You must return a value, null, or a promise that resolves to a value or null to indicate that the task was handled.

The task handler was:

async args => {
      const messages = await gmail_tester.get_messages(
        path.resolve(__dirname, "credentials.json"),
        path.resolve(__dirname, "token.json"),
        args.options
      );
      console.log(messages);
      return messages;
    }

Fix this in your setupNodeEvents method here:
/home/krupal/Desktop/Cypress Automation/RebelBase/cypress.config.js
```

In cypress's older version it's working fine.

Here is my `plugin/index.js` file

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
const debug = require("debug");
const path = require("path");

const gmail_tester = require("gmail-tester");

const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cucumber());
  
  on("task", {
    "gmail:get-messages": async args => {
      const messages = await gmail_tester.get_messages(
        path.resolve(__dirname, "credentials.json"),
        path.resolve(__dirname, "token.json"),
        args.options
      );
      console.log(messages);
      return messages;
    }
  });

  on("task", { "setUserId": (val) => { return (userId = val); } });

  on("task", { "getUserId": () => { return userId; } });
};
```

And here is my `cypress.config.js` file

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
e2e: {
    // We've imported your old cypress plugins here.
    // You may want to clean this up later by importing these.
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
    },
    baseUrl: 'https://app.dev.rebelbase.co',
    experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true,
    specPattern: 'cypress/integration/**/*.feature',
  },
})
```

And in my test I have used like...

```
cy.task("gmail:get-messages", {
    options: {
      from: "noreply@rebelbase.co",
      subject: "Join CypressTestProject01 team on RebelBase",
      include_body: true,
      // before: new Date(2021, 9, 24, 12, 31, 13), // Before September 24rd, 2019 12:31:13
      //  after: new Date(2021, 7, 23) // After August 23, 2019
    }
  }).then(emails => {
    assert.isAtLeast(
      emails.length,
      1,
      "Expected to find at least one email, but none were found!"
    );
    const body = emails[0].body.html;
    console.log(body)
    cy.log(body);

    assert.isTrue(
      body.indexOf(
        "/auth/sign-up?type=project_invitation&amp;token="
      ) >= 0,
      "Found link!"
    );

    window.token = extractData(body, startStr, endStr);

    cy.visit(
      `auth/sign-up?type=project_invitation&token=${token}&email=${randomEmail8}`
    );
  })
```

Comment: It is working with Cypress 10.6.0 and typescript, maybe try to bump Cypress version?

Comment: @LukasLewandowski I have tried to change the cypress version. but show the same error